# How to find out if the "TextChanged" event is fired if user is typing into a textbox or myTextBox.Text is called programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

> Is there a way to find out if the "TextChanged" event is fired because
>
> 1. the user is typing into a textbox or
> 2. the programmer called myTextBox.Text = "something"?

Just to give you some color on this, I don't want to react when the user is typing each letter into the textbox so I am using the "Validated" event to catch when the user is done so I can react. The problem is I don't have a way to catch when the programmer does "myTextbox.Text = "something". The only way I know to catch changes there is to use TextChanged but then I don't want to be reacting when the user is typing each letter into the textbox. Any suggestions?

Comment: ?? aren't the programmers under your control?

Comment: What is the context that you need to validate programmer input for your textbox like this? Shouldn't the programmer know what is valid input and be checking that before setting the text to something?  A simple validation could be added to the myTextbox.Text property(override the default Text property) as well if you dont want the check to be performed in each place in the code where the text is set.

Comment: I am creating a "Formatted" textbox which will render the text in the textbox with a format string when the textbox's text has been entered (like a mask but more customizable)

Comment: To deal with typing, use the key_down or key_pressed events.

Comment: @Denis then you can override the set method of the Text Property of your formatted textbox.  This will allow you to format the string whenever  `myTextBox.Text = "something"` is called

Comment: you mean **after** the textbox looses its focus, or **while** the user types in?

Comment: cjk - Not sure what you mean, I have no need to deal with typing events, see original question.

Comment: @vulkanino he wants to validate when a programmer changes the .Text property(he already has validation on user input)

Comment: @vulkanino, neither. I would like an event that (1) I can catch when the programmer using my textbox does: myTextBox.Text = "something" and (2) NOT trigger every time the user is typing a character in the textbox. (this is the reason why TextChanged doesn't work, it catches #2)

Comment: @jzworkman - so simple but I didn't think of it... thanks! Feel free to put that as answer...

Comment: you definitely need to handle the `Validating` event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will guess that you're creaing a UserControl that other developers will use, thus "end-user" programmers may set the text programmatically. I think the simplest thing would be to follow @jzworkman's suggestion and make a class that overrides the Text property setter. As @vulkanino notes, you should probably raise and catch the *Validating* event, though.

```
public class TextBoxPlus : TextBox {
    public event CancelEventHandler ProgrammerChangedText;
    protected void OnProgrammerChangedText(CancelEventArgs e) {
        CancelEventHandler handler = ProgrammerChangedText;
        if (handler != null) { handler(this, e); }
    }

    public override string Text {
        get {
            return base.Text;
        }
        set {
            string oldtext = base.Text;
            base.Text = value;
            CancelEventArgs e = new CancelEventArgs();
            OnProgrammerChangedText(e);
            if (e.Cancel) base.Text = oldtext;
        }
    }
}
```

In your source, add the same handler to both the Validating and ProgrammerChangedText events:

```
// Somewhere...
textBoxPlus1.Validating += textBoxPlus1_Validating;
textBoxPlus1.ProgrammerChangedText += textBoxPlus1_Validating;

void textBoxPlus1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
    decimal d;
    if (!Decimal.TryParse(textBoxPlus1.Text, out d)) {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont know why someone downvoted you so I added an upvote since this is a well thought out answer and limits the code re-use

Comment: This is the way I went in the end with the RaiseEvent (same as @jzworkman with the "RaiseEvent" feature). Wish I could mark both as answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

So in your "Formatted" Textbox class:

```
public override String Text{
   get{return text;}
   set
   {
      //perform validation/formatting
      this.text = formattedValue;
   }
```

this should allow you to format the text when it is changed by a programmer, the user input validation will still need to be handled in the validating event.

Comment: Exactly! So simple, just didn't think of it... No idea why people are marking this down... This is exactly what I was looking for - looking at events was the wrong way - I needed to tune my brain to a different station and look at overriding properties/methods.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to perform validation, use the `Validating` event, not the `Validated` (which comes when it is too late to act).

That said, what's the **real** need here?

> The Validating event is supplied an object of type CancelEventArgs. If
>   you determine that the control's data is not valid, you can cancel the
>   Validating event by setting this object's Cancel property to true. If
>   you do not set the Cancel property, Windows Forms will assume that
>   validation succeeded for that control, and raise the Validated event.

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603.aspx)

Comment: Validating/Validated events DO NOT fire when you are doing myTextBox.Text = "something" so this doesn't work.

Answer (score -3):

```
// This is the manual way, which is an alternative to the first way.
// Type 'this.TextChanged += ' into your form's constructor.
// Then press TAB twice, and you will have a new event handler.
this.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox1_TextChanged);

void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //put the logic here for your validation/requirements for validation
    // ex.  if (textbox1.Text=="something") {//don't validate}
    //
}
```

Comment: This will be called each time a user types a new character into the textbox which the OP does not want.  He wants when the `myTextbox.Text` property is set to something new.